# Merge Two Kaplan Meier Curve with ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have two different data set, which basically contains the same data, but one is for baseline age 19 or younger (`data.all.agefs.under19`) and the other one is for older than 19 (`data.all.agefs.above19`)

The survival object of each is defined as:

```
surv.all.agefs.under19 <- Surv(time = data.all.agefs.under19$follow.up.years, event = data.all.agefs.under19$death.specific)
surv.all.agefs.above19 <- Surv(time = data.all.agefs.above19$follow.up.years, event = data.all.agefs.above19$death.specific)
```

The Cox PH model is defined as:

```
cox.all.agefs.under19 <- coxph(surv.all.agefs.under19 ~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3, data = data.all.agefs.under19)
cox.all.agefs.above19 <- coxph(surv.all.agefs.above19 ~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3, data = data.all.agefs.above19)
```

I would like to create a plot with Kaplan Meier curves for both, but so far, I can only create one for each one using ggsurvplot:

```
ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(survfit(cox.all.agefs.under19), data = data.all.agefs.under19, palette = "#2E9FDF", ggtheme = theme_minimal(), legend = "none")
ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(survfit(cox.all.agefs.above19), data = data.all.agefs.above19, palette = "#2E9FDF", ggtheme = theme_minimal(), legend = "none")
```

So how do I merge the two curves into the same plot?

Answer (score 2):

You can append the data into one long data frame and define a variable `agegrp` to distinguish the two age groups.  Then you can plot as shown below.

```
df1 <- lung
df1$agegrp <- df1$sex

fitme <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ agegrp, data = df1) 

  ggsurv2 <- plot(fitme ,  
                  xlim = c(0,1200),
                  main = "Survival curves based on Kaplan-Meier estimates",
                  xlab = "Time in days",      # customize   X axis label.
                  ylab = "Overall survival probability"  # Y axis label
  )
  temp <- lines(fitme, lwd=2:1, col = c("red", "blue"))
  text(temp, c("Under19", "Above19"), adj= -.1) # labels just past the ends
```

[image: output]

**Update:**

Use ggsurvplot as shown below

```
ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(
    fitme,                   # survfit object with calculated statistics.
    data = df1,              # data used to fit survival curves.
    risk.table = TRUE,       # show risk table.
    pval = TRUE,             # show p-value of log-rank test.
    conf.int = TRUE,         # show confidence intervals for
    # point estimates of survival curves.
    palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"),
    xlim = c(0,1200),         # present narrower X axis, but not affect
    # survival estimates.
    xlab = "Time in days",    # customize X axis label.
    break.time.by = 100,      # break X axis in time intervals by 500.
    ggtheme = theme_light(),  # customize plot and risk table with a theme.
    risk.table.y.text.col = T,# colour risk table text annotations.
    risk.table.height = 0.25, # the height of the risk table
    risk.table.y.text = FALSE,# show bars instead of names in text annotations
    # in legend of risk table.
    ncensor.plot = TRUE,      # plot the number of censored subjects at time t
    ncensor.plot.height = 0.25,
    conf.int.style = "step",  # customize style of confidence intervals
    surv.median.line = "hv",  # add the median survival pointer.
    legend.labs = c("Under19", "Above19")  # change legend labels.
  )
```

[image: output2:]

Answer (score 1):

There's another possible way, also within `survminer` package:

```
colnames(data.all.agefs.under19) <- paste0(colnames(data.all.agefs.under19), "_u19")
colnames(data.all.agefs.above19) <- paste0(colnames(data.all.agefs.above19), "_a19")

data.all.agefs <- cbind(data.all.agefs.under19, data.all.agefs.above19)

ggsurvplot_combine(list(under19 = survfit(Surv(follow.up.years_u19, death.specific_u19) ~ factor1_u19 + factor2_u19 + factor3_u19, data = data.all.agefs), 
                        above19 = survfit(Surv(follow.up.years_a19, death.specific_a19) ~ factor1_a19 + factor2_a19 + factor3_a19, data = data.all.agefs)), 
                   data = data.all.agefs)
```